# Will Proguard or the Compiler Precalculate TimeUnit.Minutes.toMillis(120)

Tags: java, android, proguard

Currently I have a class with the following *[effectively constant](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal)* field.

```
private static final long ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
```

This is fine, but still not the most readable code in the world. What I'd rather use is the following:

```
private static final long ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT_MS = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);
```

Which clearly states I want the time to be 1 minute but that the field is milliseconds.

My question is will either the compiler or perhaps proguard fix this so there is no performance hit? If there will be a performance hit, can I expect that it is a one time hit per instance of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will be a one-time hit on class loading, and it will be such a tiny fraction of class loading that it's probably not even measurable against the overhead of loading the class in the first place.

No, the compiler can't figure it out, and I would be fairly surprised if ProGuard could, but it really doesn't matter.